# API unit test using chai giving wrong result

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mocha.js, chai, chai-http

I am writing unit test for my API which uses nodejs and mongoose. I am using mocha, chai, and chai-http to do unit testing.

I am testing a POST request that creates a customer. The first test creates a customer, and it passes. The last test will try to create a customer but should fail since the email already exist, but that fails since the request creates a new customer.

I tried doing the requests manually using postman and it gives the right behaviour.

Here are the tests:

```
describe('Customer', () => {

//Before each test we empty the database
beforeEach((done) => {
    Customer.remove({}, (err) => {
        done();
    });
});

// Creating Customer test
describe('POST Account - Creating customer account', () => {

    it('creating a user with correct arguments', (done) => {

        // defining the body
        var body = {
            first_name : "Abdulrahman",
            last_name : "Alfayad",
            email: "test@test.com",
            password: "123"
        };

        chai.request(server)
        .post('/api/customer/account')
        .send(body).end((err, res) => {
            res.body.should.have.property('status').and.is.equal('success');
            res.body.should.have.property('message').and.is.equal('customer was created');
            done();
        });
    });

    it('creating a user with incorrect arguments', (done) => {

        // defining the body
        var body = {
            first_name: "Abdulrahman",
            email: "test@test.com",
        };

        chai.request(server)
            .post('/api/customer/account')
            .send(body).end((err, res) => {
                res.body.should.have.property('status').and.is.equal('failure');
                res.body.should.have.property('message').and.is.equal('no arguments were passed');
                done();
            });
    });

    it('creating a user with an already existing email in the DB', (done) => {

        // defining the body
        var body = {
            first_name: "Abdulrahman",
            last_name: "Alfayad",
            email: "test@test.com",
            password: "123"
        };

        chai.request(server)
            .post('/api/customer/account')
            .send(body).end((err, res) => {
                res.body.should.have.property('status').and.is.equal('failure');
                res.body.should.have.property('message').and.is.equal('email already exist');
                done();
            });
    });

});
```

});

Comment: So what result actually comes back from the server? Do you perform any cleanup of users per test?

Comment: yes, I have edited the code snippet to give you a better idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel that this is because you use `beforeEach` to empty the customer database. `beforeEach` hook will be executed before each test so when you were running the email scenario test, your database actually was empty.

The easiest way to solve it is to create a new customer again before the existing email scenario such as:

```
it('creating a user with an already existing email in the DB', (done) => {

  // NOTE: Create a user with email "test@test.com"

  // defining the body
  var body = {
    first_name: "Abdulrahman",
    last_name: "Alfayad",
    email: "test@test.com",
    password: "123"
  };

  chai.request(server)
    .post('/api/customer/account')
    .send(body).end((err, res) => {
      res.body.should.have.property('status').and.is.equal('failure');
      res.body.should.have.property('message').and.is.equal('email already exist');
      done();
    });
});
```

Hope it works

Comment: Thanks that works, I created a customer then tried to create another one and it gave me the right output

Comment: @Fayad awesome 